# Close action button on action button item click swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xArCnGGzZEE) tuitorial for creating action button. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fyogeshpatelios%2FSwift-4---Easy-way-to-create-Floating-Action-Button-in-iOS-Application-Hindi..git&event=video_description&v=xArCnGGzZEE&redir_token=BVDXtr6jMh2myHTIWady7QKyVEF8MTU2MjMzNjg5NkAxNTYyMjUwNDk2) is the whole project code.

```
var actionButton : ActionButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupButtons()
}

func setupButtons(){
    let google = ActionButtonItem(title: "Google", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "a1"))
    google.action = { item in self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red }
    let twitter = ActionButtonItem(title: "Twitter", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "a2"))
    twitter.action = { item in self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue }
    let facebook = ActionButtonItem(title: "Facebook", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "a3"))
    let linkedin = ActionButtonItem(title: "Linkedin", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "a4"))
    actionButton = ActionButton(attachedToView: self.view, items: [google, twitter, facebook, linkedin])
    actionButton.setTitle("+", forState: UIControl.State())
    actionButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 238.0/255.0, green: 130.0/255.0, blue: 130.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    actionButton.action = { button in button.toggleMenu()}
}
```

The code works perfectly but when i click on the action button item lets say Google or Twitter i want the action button to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `self.actionButton.toggleMenu()` for every `button.action`.

Example:

```
google.action = {
        item in self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.actionButton.toggleMenu()
    }
```